Trying to understand backprop with convolution mathematically
I'm trying to understand how backpropagation works mathematically with convolutions.
I have a VERY simple setup.
X input to Y output through a linear filter:
kernel = torch.ones((1, 1, 3, 3)) / 9  # Normalized kernel
the FOM is calculated from Y through some nonlinear function.
The Gradient matrix G contains the derivative of the FOM for each element in Y
Now, what is this gradient multiplied with to get the derivative of the FOM with respect to each element in X?
I know I can get this value easily but I dont know whats happening under the hood.
